# C# Recursive function call : How does this function not call itself infinitely?

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm confused as to how the following code doesn't just loop infinitely from the moment it is first called.

```
`public void Move(int discs, Stack<int> from, Stack<int> to, Stack<int> auxiliary)
{
    if(discs > 0)
    {
        Move(discs - 1, from, auxiliary, to);

        to.Push(from.Pop());
        MovesCount++;
        MoveCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        Move(discs - 1, auxiliary, to, from);
    }
}`
```

How would the code ever get past the first Move()?

Comment: It´s literally in your code: `if(discs > 0)`. Or other way round: it doesn´t do anything, when `discs <= 0`. The `discs`-value isn´t allways the same on every recursion. Simple debug it and see how the value changes.

Comment: you are decrementing discs in each recursive call, in some point the disc count will be below zero and the function will return to it caller

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple, when the `discs <= 0` it will start to unwind.

Every call to `Move(discs - 1,...)` decrements disc, so on and so forth. Basically the number first passed in just acts as a levels deep variable

Comment: Oh, ok. Sorry missed that. I assumed that wasn't changing the value. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EdwardSuzuki important to understand is, that the value of `discs` is not changed! Instead, the result of the operation `discs - 1` is passed to the recursive call of `Move()`. Within this call, the `discs` value is one smaller than on the parent level, obviously. This principle winds down each recursion level, until the value meets the abort condition - but on each level the value of `discs` is preserved.

Comment: @Nicolas Ah, I will definitely go over this again in the morning. Thank you so much for the heads up.